# Call method on specific platform only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know I can call a platform-specific method by using:

```
DependencyService.Get<ISomething>();
```

But I have a method I need to call only on one platform (Android). Instead of creating an interface and implementing it on one platform only, is there a way of calling a method in one platform?

I'm asking because creating an interface makes sense when there will be more than one implementation. But when there will be only one - I would expect there to be a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: If I were you, I'd create an implementation for all platforms and just keep it empty for some. It's readable and saves you from tens of "if android", which in my opinion pollute code a lot. Also, in c# 8 there will be default interface methods implementations, maybe you can use it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using Xamarin.Forms built in `RuntimePlatform`? For example, if you needed to do something specifically for Android only:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    //Call your method
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's to choose which platform. My question is is there a simpler way to call the method than creating an interface which should not be needed because there will only be one implementation. +1 anyway.

Comment: `Device.RuntimePlatform` returns you what OS your app is currently running on, which you can compare with the built-in device constants  `Device.Android`, `Device.iOS`, `Device.macOS`, `Device.UWP`, etc. which will return true or false if it is that platform and then call whatever method you might need to do only on that platform.